# How can I preserve case of element attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, xml-attribute

I'm using jQuery to create an XML document on the fly by utilizing the document.createElement function.  This works great for creating the structure as I am able to utilize the .appendTo function to dynamically place the correct nodes in the proper order.  The problem comes when I set the attributes of the elements I create.  As soon as they are created, they are set to lowercase and never preserve their case.  This is unacceptable because the attributes will not match their expected format downstream.

I have tried to create the XML document on the fly by concatenating strings but this will not work because of the way nodes can be nested.

Is there any way I can use the createElement approach that preserves the case of each attribute?

Answer (score 2):

first part, as you are creating HTMLNode, it will follow the DTD of HTML, that's why it turned into lowercase. You can use `.setAttributeNS(NS, key, value)` and `.creatElementNS()` for this problem.

second part, didn't get you...

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/N52Qa/

Comment: Is there any DTD that allows camelcase attributes?

Comment: specify a customized namespace, then do whatever you want.

Comment: I can confirm that "creatElementNS" with a "null" as first argument does wonders! Thank you very much!

Comment: How can I create an NS attribute directly in HTML?